# Stop the error when trying to manipulate the items of a Listbox, but no item is selected?

Tags: button, python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

I am a beginner in tkinter. I am making a list of names. You can delete, select and edit it, but if I don't select anything in the list and click these buttons, it says:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last): File
"C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__ return
self.func(*args) File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\HOW_TOUGH - NEW\Change_user.py",
line 60, in Edit (idx, ) = d ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack'''
```

I am planning to disable the buttons if the user doesn't click anything but I am not expert enough. Here's my code (it's a child window)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

class Nick:

    def __init__(self, master ):
        self.master = master
        self.window = Toplevel(master)
        self.window.title('Change User')
        self.window.geometry('300x300')
        self.window.minsize(300, 300)
        self.window.maxsize(300, 300)

        self.nickname = StringVar()

        self.lb = Listbox(self.window, selectmode = 'SINGLE')

        f= open('users.txt','r')
        rec = f.readlines()
        f.close()

        for i in rec:
            p = i.find('|')
            nickname = i[:p]
            self.lb.insert(END, nickname)

        self.lb.pack()

        self.Ed = ttk.Button(self.window, text = 'Edit', command = self.Edit).pack()
        self.Del = ttk.Button(self.window, text = 'Delete', command = self.Delete).pack()
        self.Bac = ttk.Button(self.window, text = 'Back', command = self.Back).pack()
        self.Okay = ttk.Button(self.window, text = 'Ok', command = self.Ok).pack()

    def Back(self):
        self.window.destroy()

    def Delete(self):

        d = self.lb.curselection()
        (idx, ) = d
        self.lb.delete(idx)

        f = open('users.txt','r')
        r = f.readlines()
        f.close()

        rec = r[idx]
        r.remove(rec)

        f = open('users.txt','w')
        new = ''.join(r)
        r = f.write(new)
        f.close()

        messagebox.showinfo(title='Success', message = 'Delete successful')

    def Edit(self):
        d = self.lb.curselection()
        (idx, ) = d
        import Edit as Edet
        Edet.Edit(self.master, idx)

    def Ok(self):

        d = self.lb.curselection()
        (idx, ) = d
        get = self.lb.get(idx)
        self.window.destroy()
        print (get)
        print (d)
```

Answer (score 2):

The method `curselection()` returns an empty tuple when nothing is selected. You can skip those methods just by adding a

```
if not d:
    return
```

If you want to gray out your buttons, you can do this:

```
button["state"] = DISABLED
```

Note that this won't work currently with your code as you did this:

```
self.button = ttk.Button(...).pack()
```

The problem lies in the call of `pack()` which returns `None`, effectively binding `self.button` to `None`. Just assign the button object to the variable first and then pack it. Furthermore, it's not recommended to import `*` from Tkinter because you're dropping ~190 names in your namespace. Just use

```
import tkinter as tk
```